# Get variable from tenant in Octopus

Tags: variables, octopus-deploy

Is there any way to get a variable from tenant in Octopus server?

I already extracting variable from projects, using code below, but this method is not working for tenants:

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Octopus-Cmdlets\0.4.4\Octopus-Cmdlets.psd1"

connect-octoserver http://octohost.cloudapp.azure.com:8082 API-12345678901234567890
$raw = (Get-OctoVariable someproject somevariable | Where-Object { $_.Environment -eq "DEV" } )
$jsonfile = "c:\dataapi.json"
$raw.Value | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $jsonfile -Encoding UTF8
$data = Get-Content $jsonfile -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json
$data | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $jsonfile -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: I haven't used that module, but I have used the OctopusClient.Dll and with it, you have to go through the tenant to get to the tenant variables

Comment: You use objects like this (pseudo-code...) tenants.GetVariables(tenantID).ProjectVariables[projectID].Variables[EnvironmentID]

Comment: That would be a hashtable of the project variable templates for that tenant.

Comment: Thanks for the info - will try to dig in this direction!

Answer (score 0):

There is at least the following way to get a variable from a tenant in Octopus Deploy. I got this working with making OctopusClient.dll calls.

```
Add-Type -Path $OctopusClientDll #this should point to the dll
$Endpoint = New-Object Octopus.Client.OctopusServerEndpoint $octopusURI, $apiKey
$Repository = New-Object Octopus.Client.OctopusRepository $Endpoint
$TenantEditor = $Repository.Tenants.CreateOrModify($TenantName)
$Vars = $TenantEditor.Variables.Instance.LibraryVariables
$VarSet = $Vars[$COMMON_TENANT_VARSET_ID] # you need to know this
$VarTemplate = $VarSet.Templates | Where-Object -Property Name -eq "Tenant.VariableName"
$VariableValue = $VarSet.Variables[$varTemplate.Id].Value
```